# CSS change image as hover over image with a link

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create a home button that as you "hover" over the image it will change color, im TRYING to use css to change the image on hover and that works fine because it will simply on hover replace image1 with image2 (the color changed image) BUT i cant find a way to link the image so when the person clicks it takes them to the home page.

```
<div id="homebutton">
    <img src="homelogo.png" alt="tut" width="23" height="23px">
</div>

#homebutton{
    top:6%;
    left:0.5%;
    position:fixed;
    background-image: url('homelogo.png');
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
}

#homebutton:hover{
    top:6%;
    left:0.5%;
    position:fixed;
    background-image: url('homelogohover.png')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a link to a home page you should change this

```
<div id="homebutton">
 <img src="homelogo.png" alt="tut" width="23" height="23px">
</div>
```

to:

```
<a href="home.html" id="homebutton">home</a>
```

Note:
You should just specify in the :hover the property you want to change, also I recommend the use of class for this instead `ID`

```
#homebutton{
  text-indent: -19999px;/*to hide the Home text in the link*/
  top:6%;
  left:0.5%;
  position:fixed;
  background-image: url('homelogo.png');
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
}

#homebutton:hover{
  background-image: url('homelogohover.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep the div (for some reason), you could add an onclick event handler.

```
<div id="homebutton" onclick="location.href='home.html'">
    <img src="homelogo.png" alt="tut" width="23" height="23px">
</div>
```